# Can I extract common code from `switch` cases with only ReSharper transformations?

Tags: c#, resharper

Give code like this:

```
switch (args[0])
{
    case "foo":
    {
        var operation = new FooOperation();
        operation.Do();
        break;
    }
    case "bar":
    {
        var operation = new BarOperation();
        operation.Do();
        break;
    }
    default: throw new Exception();
}
```

I want to pull the common parts out of the switch, like this:

```
IOperation operation;
switch (args[0])
{
    case "foo":
    {
        operation = new FooOperation();
        break;
    }
    case "bar":
    {
        operation = new BarOperation();
        break;
    }
    default: throw new Exception();
}
operation.Do();
```

And I want to do it without typing - just ReSharper transformations. Is there a way to do that?

(For a complete program that is legal and compiles, see https://gist.github.com/JayBazuzi/2457e8389d338688a9ab and https://gist.github.com/JayBazuzi/798bdca40d59e095e83b)

Comment: They're not the same thing - in your first code, `Do` won't be executed in the "default" case, whereas in your second code it would - if it actually compiles, which it doesn't at the moment.

Comment: That's true, and I was hoping to just gloss over that part so the examples wouldn't get over-long. Will fix.

Comment: I have found a partial solution with "Split Declaration and Assignment" + "Move to Outer Scope" + "Merge Variables". (If there are 3 cases, I have to do Merge Variables twice - weird). But that still leaves the `operation.Do()` part.

Comment: Jon, I've linked to Gists w/ real programs that actual compile (instead of just illustrative sketches).